# Angular2 component-to-component communication

Tags: angular

exactly what the title suggests is my question.
I will start by explaining what i have to do.

So I have a component widget. When I click on it a modal pops containing couple of items. Each item represents a different section in the main application. On click on any item a specific section will be displayed related to that item (which is a component itself).

I have no previews experience with Angular 1 or 2 so to be honest I have no idea where to start from or what should I search for. The best I come out with is `EventEmitter`, `Output`, `Input` (but those are for child-parent / parent-child communication from what i've read, which is not the case). Also I've been looking on `Observable` but i don't think this is helpful in this situation (for what i've understand i deals with server side service calls).
If you had any experience please share.
Thank you.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 2):

The code below demonstrates the communication between sibling components, parent and child components with the help of angular services.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ParentComponent } from './app.parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ ParentComponent, ChildComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ ParentComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentChildService } from './parent-child.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello from Parent</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px dotted blue;">
                <p> <b> Child message history </b> </p>
                <p *ngFor="let message of childMessages">
                    {{ message }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <child-app [id] = 1> </child-app>
            <child-app [id] = 2> </child-app>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [ ParentChildService ]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    childMessages: string[] = [];

    constructor(private parentChildService: ParentChildService) {
        parentChildService.attentionRequested$.subscribe((request) => {
            this.childMessages.push(this.parentChildService.requestedBy + ": " + request);
        });
    }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentChildService } from './parent-child.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Hello from {{ id }} child component</h2>
                <span> Message: </span> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message">
                <button (click) = "requestAttention();"> Request </button>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px dotted green;">
                <p> <b> Sibling message history </b> </p>
                <p *ngFor="let message of siblingMessages">
                    {{ message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
    message: string;
    subscription: Subscription;
    siblingMessages: string[] = [];
    @Input() id: number;

    requestAttention(): void {
        this.parentChildService.requestAttention(this.message, this.id);
    }

    constructor(private parentChildService: ParentChildService) {
        this.subscription = parentChildService.attentionRequested$.subscribe((request, id) => {
            if (this.id != this.parentChildService.requestedBy) {
                this.siblingMessages.push(this.parentChildService.requestedBy + ": " + request);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**parent-child.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ParentChildService {
    // Observable sources
    private requestAttentionSource = new Subject<string>();

    // Observable streams
    attentionRequested$ = this.requestAttentionSource.asObservable();
    requestedBy: number;

    requestAttention(request: string, id: number) {
        this.requestedBy = id;
        this.requestAttentionSource.next(request);
    }
}
```

The [gist](https://gist.github.com/dushyant89/ee32397f03f2da8acb60f22d10a6643d) demonstrates the same thing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a singleton to hold the state, and inject it everywhere I need to read the state/change the state.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service